# .mdf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, entity-framework

```
    protected void register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddUser(userName.Text, password.Text, confirm.Text);
    }

    void AddUser(string name, string pass, string confirm)
    {
        User u = new User(name, pass, confirm);

        if (u.Valid)
        {
            using (var db  = new SiteContext())
            {
                db.User.Add(u);
                db.SaveChanges(); 
            }
        }
    }
}

public class User 
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool Valid { get; set; }

    public User(string _name,string _password,string _confirm)
    {
        if (CheckPassword(_password, _confirm))
        {
            Password = _password;
            UserName = _name;
            Valid = true;
        }
        else
            Valid = false;
    }

    private bool CheckPassword(string _password, string _confirm)
    {
        if (_confirm.Equals(_confirm))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}

public class SiteContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to create a new database using Entity Framework but I always getting that exception

> Directory lookup for the file "c:\users\oren\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ResturantSite\ResturantSite\App_Data\ResturantSite.SiteContext.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors
>
> Line 28:                 using (var db  = new SiteContext())
>   Line 29:                 {
>   Line 30:                     db.User.Add(u);
>   Line 31:                     db.SaveChanges();
>   Line 32:                 }

Line 30 throws the exception

I hope somebody can help

Comment: Does the `c:\users\oren\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ResturantSite\ResturantSite\App_Data` folder exist? And if so, does the application have permission to write to it?

Comment: the folder doesent exist 
how do i know if the app have permission to write it?

Comment: Create it and see what happens!

Comment: Visual Studio has the option to do that specific folder automatically.

Comment: i am trying to create that database by entity

Comment: But it cannot create the database if the folder it wants to access doesn't exist.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Your application is missing the `App_Data` folder. Right click on your project, select `Add`, then `Add ASP.Net Folder` and choose the `App_Data` folder.

This ensures the correct folder exists for your application.

Comment: I have no Add ASP.Net Folder option in VS 2015
http://imgur.com/iRqHoMj
What should I do?

Comment: You need to add the folder in your web project, not in your class library.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed the error deleting the current Add_Data folder since I had cloned the project from a Github repository, then I added the App_Data folder again and ran the migrations with update-database command. This worked for me.